# Can we add sitecore users to TDS?

Tags: tds

Is there a way to **add users** to `sitecore TDS`?

I'm using version **6.0.0.18**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only sync roles in TDS - http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#sync-sitecore-roles If you need to move users, you can create a package of them, but that will only move the users and not their credentials. You may have to enable such users and reset their passwords in Sitecore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add just roles to Sitecore TDS, Sitecore users are not supported AFAIK.

[image]